# Bit Vector to Integer vectors of 0s and 1s

Tags: c, bitmap

I have a char[] vector, representing a bitmap, and I want to convert this to an integer vector where the nth bit in the char array corresponds to the nth entry in the integer array.

I can only think of doing it this way:
iterate through each byte, and "extract the nth bit" every time. It's simple, but it seems unnecessarily slow.

I can think of a few optimisations where, if I use "<<" and check whether the rest of the byte is 0, I can skip a few entries, but that won't add much as I expect my vector to be dense.

Any thoughts on how to make this more efficient

Thanks

Comment: `int charmap[1<<CHAR_BIT][CHAR_BIT];`

Comment: There are exactly `1<<CHAR_BIT` possible bytes so `charmap[b]` represents the byte `b`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that by checking to see char you are iterating through is < 2^i where i is the bit being checked you are approaching a lower bound on the problem.

In the following code I am using (1 << j) to be equal to 2^j and the & is the bitwise and operator, which will check if the value of the bit at that index is 1 or 0.

This runs in liner time considering the length of a byte is constant.

```
int i;
for(i=0;i<sizeof charVector;i++){
    int j;
    for(j=0;j<8;j++){
        if (charVector[i]< (1 << j)){
            break;
        } else {
            intVector[i*8 + j] = charVector[i] & (1 << j);
        }
     }
}
```